# JsonCpp: how to convert/serialize an object to Json::Value

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

Is it possible to convert/serialize an object to `Json::Value` in jsonCpp?

For example:
I have class

```
class MyClass
{
   std::string str1;
   std::string str2;
   std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map1;
   std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map2;
   bool boo1;

   void func1();
   void func2();
}

MyClass myObject;
```

and I would like to change the `myObject` to `Json::Value`, something maybe like

```
Json::Value myJson = JsonParse(myObject) //not a real code
```

Comment: Hi. Please provide a [mcve] of your problem and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Such generic conversion would require type introspection, which in general C++ does not support. But you can always manually write such a converter per type.

Comment: You cannot write a function which takes an object OF ANY CLASS, so unless you want your JsonParse work with MyClass only (or with a finite set of classes, and you write a function explicitly for every class), it is impossible.

Comment: I did a similar thing, but using the RapidJSON library. You need to manually populate the members values. The good this is that you can encapsulate this functionally. Take a look at the general idea here: https://gotask.net/programming/serialize-and-deserialize-object-in-cpp-using-rapidjson/